# Issue with Spring Data Neo4j migration from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0 RC1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to migrate an SDN project from the current stable version (2.3.3) to the 3.0.0 RC1 version wich supports Neo4j 2.0.
The project is a WAR which is deployed on a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 server and uses EJBs which access Neo4j via *@Autowired* `Neo4jOperations` object and `GraphRepository<T>` objects.
The auto wiring is supported using the `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` interceptor annotation.
The SDN configuration is given by the following lines in the spring xml configuration file:

> ```
> <context:annotation-config/>
> <context:spring-configured/>
> <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
>     <constructor-arg index="0" value="my.db"/>
> </bean>
> <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.my.neo4j.repository"/>
> <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
> <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
> ```

Everything works fine when using the 2.3.3 SDN version, but unfortunately using the 3.0.0 RC1 gives the following error while deploying:

> javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to
>   resolve a bean for
>   'org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext'
>   with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(),
>   @javax.enterprise.inject.Default()].
>           at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.cdi.Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.cdi.Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(Neo4jCdiRepositoryExtension.java:82)
>   ...

I really have no idea about what's wrong with my project, I would be grateful to anyone that could help me in solving this issue.

**UPDATE:** Same issue with the 3.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Any solution yet? I am having the same problem, if I introduce a repository which extends "GraphRepository".

Comment: @MarcusSchultö It's been solved in the current version 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor for `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` anymore.

You have to use the `GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean` that I added instead.

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="target/config-test"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I've just tried it, unfortunately I'm still getting exactly the same error. My impression is that with my configuration SDN expects the graphDatabaseService bean to be injected somewhere using Java EE CDI.